# GCP Dataflow- read CSV file from Compute Engine VM and write into BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

GCP Dataflow- read CSV file from Storage and write into BigQuery

Comment: Can you detail more?

Comment: Yes sure, I have files present on Google Compute Engine VM instance and wanted to load that  files using Google Cloud Dataflow into BigQuey

Comment: Is your file require a lot of transformation before being loaded into BigQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Dataflow can't read files from the disk of VM. The best way is to upload your file into a Bucket and then to use [BuiltIn connector](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/). In Java, I use `FileIO`.